# AppleScript Editor, write message to the "Result" window

Tags: macos, logging, applescript

I am using the Mac OS X Apple Script Editor and (while debugging) instead of writing a lot of `display dialog` statements, I'd like to write the results of some calculation in the window below, called "Result" (I have the German UI here, so the translation is a guess). So is there a write/print statement that I can use for putting messages in the "standard out" window? I am not asking to put the messages in a logfile on the file system, it is purely temporary.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use the [log](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW49) command, which puts messages into the **Log History** window, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: If you want to only see the results from your log statements, you can tap the Events and Replies buttons so that they are unhighlighted.

Comment: Hooray broken images from before SO had a deal with Imgur :D

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero: thanks for the heads up - I just added a new screen shot.

Comment: @minseong: in what way does it not work ? What happens when you get to the `log` statement ?

Comment: @PaulR it just doesn't post anything. I was using it (trying to) inside a tell block though.

Comment: OK - try it on its own first to make sure it works in isolation, perhaps ?

Answer (score 14):

Log is the correct way of doing this; however, if your user base is more familiar with shell script you can do the following.

```
set val to 123
do shell script "echo The value: " & val
```

Output

```
Result:
"The value: 123"
```

With this approach you don’t constantly have to telling users that they need to enable ‘Show Log’